# List files that have both keywords with grep

Tags: grep

I would like to list the files (using `grep -r`) that have both of the two keywords (not necessarily on the same line): `word1`, `word2`.

When I do the following, I get the files that have `word1` or `word2`:

```
grep -r 'word1\|word2' .
```

I also tried the following:

```
grep -r 'word1|word2'
```

which does not return anything, but I'm not sure if it's because there are no files that have both these keywords, or there are no files that have both these keywords **on the same line**.

How can I get the list of files that contain the two keywords somewhere in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a list of files containing one keyword, then search this list for the second, as in:

```
grep -l word2 $(grep -rl word1 .)
```

If you want to show the matches, add a third `grep`, as in:

```
grep -E 'word1|word2' `grep -l word2 $(grep -rl word1 .)`
```

It is also possible to use `sed` to perform `grep` functions, and it may be possible to do what you want in a single scan with `sed`, but I haven't thought that through.